# Get data from adjoining cell - MS Access - Java

Tags: java, database, swing, ms-access

I'm writing a Java Swing program for a college library. This program is connected to an MS Access database.

[image]

The program has a `JTextField` where the "Number" has to  be entered. Below the TextField, there's a `JButton`. After the number is entered and the button is clicked, I want the program to print out the respective "Department"

For example :

[image]

When the user types the Number "3" in the `JTextField` and clicks the 'Enter'
button, I want my program to print out "Computers" i.e the data from the adjoining cell.

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: rather than a big description, please provide your code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

You will need a JDBC driver for MS Access, [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is reasonable popular.

You will then need to:

1. Load the JDBC driver
2. Connect to the database
3. Execute a SQL query which can select the data you want based on your critera
4. Retrieve the data from the resulting data set

For example...

```
try {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://<mdb or accdb file path>", user, password)) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT department FROM Table1 WHERE ID = ?")) {
            stmt.setInt(1, 3); // Use a variable for the ID
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                // We're only expecting a single row...
                if (rs.next()) {
                    String department = rs.getString(1);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might also want to take a look at a [SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by! Is there any way to get the ID and then get the data from the Department column?

Comment: Yes, instead of passing `3` in `stmt.setInt(1, 3);` pass it a variable with the value of the ID you want...